# Java : Synchronization of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this piece of code below as shown .
Our Application runs on 5 web servers controlled by a Load Balancer ,all connecting to one Memcache instance .

I guess that this piece of synchrnozation works only for one Instance .

Please let me know how can i synchrnoze this piece of code when 5 web servers are trying to access the Memcache

```
public class Memcache {
    private MemcachedClient memclient = null;  
    private static Memcache instance = null;

    public static Memcache getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            try {
                synchronized (Memcache.class) {
                    instance = new Memcache();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Memcache() throws IOException {
        MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder();
        memclient = builder.build();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not initialize it like this?

```
private static Memcache instance = new Memcache();
```

Bare in mind that what you tried to achieve at the synchronization here is problematic, 
As two threads might pass the (if (instance == null) (a context switch might be after that line) 
So you can consider the [double check pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_check_locking), 
BUt at some version of java there is a problem with it. 
At the link I provided , there is info about problem, and 
in [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html) link, you can read about Singleton with the volatile keyword.

I still would go for the option I suggested above.

Comment: +1 this is the cleanest solution. Double-checked locking is messy.

Comment: This lets you declare the field `final` as well. I believe this suggestion works because the JVM has to implicitly synchronize class-loading. That seems great: they'll probably have made that synchronization as efficient as possible.

Comment: @zsake , so you mean to say i should use volatile here , private static  volatile Memcache instance = null;

Comment: @PreethiJain , this will work even without the volatile. No usage of static fields of the class until it is fully loaded and statically initialized via the class loader.

Comment: So 
you mean i should do like this , inside the syncronized block 
synchronized (Memcache.class) {
 private static Memcache instance = new Memcache();
}

Comment: Yes, if you feel this is a correct answer, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was using Java 1.6 , so i guess the code what i posted in the question will work fine as till java 1.4 it has got  this problem . what do you suggest , do i need to change ??

Comment: @PreethiJain - your original code will not work. A context switch might occur as I explained. I would suggest to fix the way I suggested. I did that lots of times on JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lazily initialized ClassHolder pattern to implement synchronized access to a class. Because the Memcache is initialized with a static initializer, it doesn't need more synchronization constructs. The first call to getInstance() by any thread causes MemcacheHolder to be ***loaded*** and initialized and the Memcache instance to make itself available to the calling code.

```
public class MemcacheFactory{

  private static class MemcacheHolder {
        public static Memcache instance = new Memcache();
    }

    public static Memcache getInstance() {
        return MemcacheFactory.MemcacheHolder.instance;
    }

}
```